# Dynamic select list from link

Tags: jquery, list, select

Can someone help me write javascript (jquery) code, which will build the select lists of data from link: 
http://nosal.ig.pl/webcm/module/TiShopSearchValues/search?format=JSON&name=field_attr_id_1_like&nodup=1&query=

JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "value":"210 mbar",
      "label":"210 mbar",
      "id":"19"
   },
   {  
      "value":"30 mbar",
      "label":"30 mbar",
      "id":"13"
   },
   {  
      "value":"Atrybut 1",
      "label":"Atrybut 1",
      "id":"14"
   },
   {  
      "value":"inne",
      "label":"inne",
      "id":"12"
   }
]
```

The script should build the following list:

```
<select name="field_attr_id_1_like">
    <option value="210 mbar">210 mbar</option>
    <option value="30 mbar">30 mbar</option>
    <option value="Atrybut 1">Atrybut 1</option>
    <option value="inne">inne</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: And please show what you've tried. SO is for helping you fix your code, not getting other people to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++){
    $('#field_attr_id_1_like').append('<option value="' + myJson[i].value + '">' + myJson[i].label + '</option>')
}
```

Check the jsfiddle with full example: http://jsfiddle.net/nbLF7/1/

UPDATE: in my example the select has "id" instead of "name" attribute but if you wish to use a "name" instead use this selector:

```
$('select[name="field_attr_id_1_like"]').append('<option value="' + myJson[i].value + '">' + myJson[i].label + '</option>');
```

Comment: How to load option automaticly without 'click'? I'm sorry but I have no knowledge :(

Comment: Well, then just put the code in $(document).ready(function() { //put code here });

Comment: BTW. if you really don't know how to do it, I would suggest some book. These are really complete basics and without them is impossible to code.